# i get this error when debug my Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, sdk

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
/D:/program/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:4919:27: Error: Expected an identifier, but got ','.
Try inserting an identifier before ','.
Widget build() => state.,build(this);
^
/D:/program/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:4919:27: Error: Expected a class member, but got ','.

Widget build() => state.,build(this);
^
/D:/program/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:4919:34: Error: 'this' can't be used as an identifier because it's a keyword.
Try renaming this to be an identifier that isn't a keyword.

Widget build() => state.,build(this);
^^^^
/D:/program/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:4919:28: Error: 'build' is already declared in this scope.
Widget build() => state.,build(this);

```
                       ^^^^^
```

/D:/program/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:4919:10: Context: Previous declaration of 'build'.
Widget build() => state.,build(this);
^^^^^

/D:/program/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:4888:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'StatefulElement' is missing implementations for these members:

- StatefulElement.build
  Try to either
- provide an implementation,
- inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
- mark the class as abstract, or
- provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class StatefulElement extends ComponentElement {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/D:/program/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:4919:28: Context: 'StatefulElement.build' is defined here.
Widget build() => state.,build(this);
^^^^^
/D:/program/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:4919:27: Error: Expected  an identifier, but got ''.
Try inserting an identifier before ''.
Widget build() => state.,build(this);
^
/D:/program/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:4919:26: Error: Expected ';' after this.

Widget build() => state.,build(this);
^
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\program\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'D:\program\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

this error hapend when dupg my flutter app how can solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is described here:

> /D:/program/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:4919:28: Context: 'StatefulElement.build' is defined here. Widget build() => state.,build(this);

I expect you have debugged your code and maybe accidentally put the comma in the `framework.dart` file.

Go to this specific file, double-check and remove the comma.